# Find when people change attribute in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to make a list of instances where somebody changed their `pref`, and report what happened to their `drink` at that time, ignoring all times when they didn't change their `pref`.

The `name`-`location` pair is a unique identifier for a person, and remains constant for each person.

The only idea I've had is a script that goes through each `name`-`location`-`pref` triple, finds all entries that match that match the name and location and don't match. I hope that makes sense. Does Mongo have a simpler or more computationally feasible way to do this?

```
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2001,  pref: 'vanilla', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2002,  pref: 'vanilla', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2003,  pref: 'vanilla', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2004,  pref: 'chocolate', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2005,  pref: 'chocolate', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'bob', location: 90210, year: 2006,  pref: 'chocolate', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'mary', location: 90210, year: 2005,  pref: 'chocolate', drink:'coffee'}
{name: 'mary', location: 90210, year: 2006,  pref: 'chocolate', drink:'coffee'}
```

Script should find the fact that Bob changed his `pref` and return the fact that he had a change on that field.  It should not return anything about Mary, because she didn't change her `pref`. Ideally it would report that when Bob changed his `pref`, his `drink` went `coffee` -> `coffee`.

Comment: Can you show some documents and the solution that you have tried so far?

Comment: Does `pref` have a default value? If yes, then it's easy - find all documents where `pref` isn't default value (which means it's been changed at some point)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @Hatshepsut: well, then you're out of luck. Mongo doesn't track field updates. So if you didn't record it yourself (in a `pref_changed_at`), then it's not possible.

Comment: Yeah, you need to explain more. With examples of documents, perhaps. Currently, it's very unclear. Just try reading it out loud.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev alright, tried to clear it up, added sample documents too.

Comment: @Hatshepsut: yeah thanks, it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I could do using aggregate command.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                'name' : '$name',
                'location' : '$location',
                'pref' : '$pref'
            },
            year : {
                '$min' : '$year'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort : {
            "_id.name" : 1,
            year : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                'name' : '$_id.name',
                'location' : '$_id.location'
            },
            from : {$first : '$_id.pref'},
            to : {$last : '$_id.pref'}
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 1,
            from : 1,
            to : 1,
            from_to_eq : {$eq : ['$from', '$to']}
        }
    },
    {
        $match : {
            from_to_eq : false
        }
    }
])
```

What it does is:

Aggregates by `name`, `location` and `pref` and finds lowest year.
Then does sorting by `name` and `year`.

After that finds first and last `pref` for each name and location as `from` and `to` respectively.
And then projects those documents where `from` and `to` are not same.

Following will be the result from this command

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "bob",
        "location" : 90210
    },
    "from" : "vanilla",
    "to" : "chocolate",
    "from_to_eq" : false
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming you need to keep a historical record of preferences? If not you can simply update the existing document for each person with their new preference and be on your way.

If you need a historical record, you must either capture all preferences for Bob in a single document, or you should create a new document for each preference that Bob has. If there are likely to be many preference updates, pushing preferneces into an array is bad schema design as you have no idea how big the document can grow.

This can be done in a few ways.

You should include a field either with a timestamp or with a version. For example:

```
{ name: 'bob', 
  location: '90210',
  pref: 'vanilla',
  drink: 'coffee',
  v: 1
}
```

The next time that bob updates his preferences you simply insert a new document with the following:

```
{ name: 'bob', 
  location: '90210',
  pref: 'vanilla',
  drink: 'coffee',
  v: 2
}
```

Then when you query for the latest preference you simply do:

```
db.customers.find({name:'bob}).sortby({v:-1}).limit(1)
```

This is good for finding the newest preference, but bad for finding the previous preferences. It also has a fair amount of extra data as you store multiple documents for each user.

One other method may be to store the current preference in a field and then store previous preferences in an array:

```
{ name: 'bob', 
  location: '90210',
  pref: 'vanilla',
  drink: 'coffee',
  prev_pref: ['chocolate', 'syrup']
}
```

This way you can get the current preference of bob and a record of his past preferences just with a simple:

```
db.customers.find({name:'bob'})
```

Now here is the extra part - do you need to do something once a preference has been updated i.e. Bob updates his preferences causes some kind of trigger event in MongoDB? This will need to be handled in the application as mongodb does not support triggers nor a change notification API.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. The historical record is stored in the way that each person-year gets a new document, as shown in the sample documents above.

Comment: I would do the following - When someone (bob) updates their preference I would first do a db.customres.find({name:"bob"}) to check bobs current preference. If the new value is different from the old value, I would do a db.customers.update({name:"bob"},{$set:{prefUpdated:true}},false,true). Then I would be able to find all people who have their preferences changed by searching for db.customers.find({pref-changed:true}), which will bring bob back, but not mary.